# Change Google Apps Script from printing array from active cell to specific sheet and range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to tell the script to print to a specific sheet named '**Creative**' and starting in cell **B2**. Instead of printing to The code, I'm using the code below. Thanks so much for any help you can offer.

```
function getFileArray(folderId){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var fileList = [];

  //Loop though files and add names and urls to the array
  while (files.hasNext()){ 
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();    
    var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
    fileList = fileList.concat([[fileName, fileUrl]]);
  }
   //See returned fileList in a log
  //Logger.log( fileList ) //Preview Returned Array      
  return fileList


}


//Prints any 2D array to a range that starts with the selected cell

function printArrayToSelection(twoDimArr){  
  var firstCell = SS.getActiveCell();
  var lastCell = firstCell.offset(twoDimArr.length - 1, twoDimArr[0].length - 1);
  var destinationRange = SS.getActiveSheet().getRange(
    firstCell.getA1Notation() + ':' + lastCell.getA1Notation());
  destinationRange.setValues(twoDimArr);

}

//Print the actual data
function printFileArray(){
  printArrayToSelection(getFileArray('FOLDERIDHERE'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the sheet for the destination range, you can use the getSheetByName method and pass "Creative" as an argument.

To get the destination range, I would recommend using the getRange method and passing the row, column, number of rows, and number of columns as arguments. For your case, this would be `2, 2, twoDimArr.length, twoDimArr[0].length`

The documentation for this method can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

```
function printArrayToSelection(twoDimArr){  
  var firstCell = SS.getActiveCell();
  var lastCell = firstCell.offset(twoDimArr.length - 1, twoDimArr[0].length - 1);
  var destinationRange = SS.getSheetByName("Creative").getRange(2, 2, twoDimArr.length, twoDimArr[0].length);
  destinationRange.setValues(twoDimArr);
}
```

Comment: @BrianYoung No problem. If you're happy with this solution, I would appreciate it if you could mark this answer as useful and accept it.

Comment: I accepted the answer but my rep is too low to mark as useful. I will come back to this once I have 15 rep!